# PHP XML. How to check if value of a tag is 0

Tags: php, xml

I am receiving the following xml file:

```
<FEEDBACKLIST>
<SUMMARY>
<MODE>service</MODE>
<VENDORLOGON/>
<VENDORREF/>
<TOTALSERVICECOUNT>0</TOTALSERVICECOUNT>
<TOTALPRODUCTCOUNT>0</TOTALPRODUCTCOUNT>
<COUNT>0</COUNT>
<TITLE/>
<BEST>100</BEST>
<WORST>0</WORST>
<AVERAGE>??</AVERAGE>
<START>1</START>
<LIMIT>20</LIMIT>
</SUMMARY>
</FEEDBACKLIST>
```

Can I check if the COUNT is 0 and if it is I would like to resend the xml request with different parameters.

I am receiving the it this way:

```
$curdir = getcwd();




$logon = array_key_exists('logon', $_GET) ? $_GET['logon'] : null;
$limit = array_key_exists('limit', $_GET) ? $_GET['limit'] : null;
$mode = array_key_exists('mode', $_GET) ? $_GET['mode'] : null;
$vendorref = array_key_exists('vendorref', $_GET) ? $_GET['vendorref'] : null;
$suppressnegatives = array_key_exists('suppressnegatives', $_GET) ? $_GET['suppressnegatives'] : null;

$xml_filename = "http://www.x.com/filename/xmlfeed.jsp?logon=".$logon;
if ($limit)
    $xml_filename .= "&limit=".$limit;
if ($vendorref)
  $xml_filename.="&vendorref=".$vendorref; 
if ($mode)
  $xml_filename.="&mode=".$mode; 
if ($suppressnegatives)
  $xml_filename.="&negativesanswered=true";



if (phpversion() < "5"){
    $xmldoc = domxml_open_file( $xml_filename);
    $xsldoc = domxml_xslt_stylesheet_file ( $curdir."/feedback.xsl");
    $result = $xsldoc->process($xmldoc);
    echo $result->dump_mem();
}
else
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
    $doc->load($curdir."/feedback.xsl");    
    $xsl->importStyleSheet($doc);
    $doc->load($xml_filename);
    echo $xsl->transformToXML($doc);
```

I think I need to check before it echo's out the $xsl with getElementsbyTagName but not sure on how to use this.

Any help welcome

Comment: The only relevant code you've posted is `$doc = new DOMDocument();` and `$doc->load($xml_filename);`. Rather than having the specific problem the title suggests, you seem to be looking for advice on how to use the `DOM` extension (assuming that the PHP/4 code is there for historical reasons and you don't really want to maintain it). I suggest you browse the docs or find a tutorial and get back here when you've got the basics.

Comment: I put the full code there to give the clear picture of what I am trying to do, so if anyone looks at it I hope it is clear. Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the PHP 4 support, have fun traversing the DOM. If you can remove it and support only PHP 5 use the DOMXpath::evaluate().

```
$xml = '<FEEDBACKLIST><SUMMARY><COUNT>0</COUNT></SUMMARY></FEEDBACKLIST>';

$dom = new DOMDOcument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(/FEEDBACKLIST/SUMMARY/COUNT)'));
```

Output:

```
string(1) "0"
```