# Get the value of an attribute from xml file then use it in a string with php?

Tags: php, xml

This might seem easy but I can't get my head around it:
I have the following incoming xml

```
<FEEDBACKLIST>
<SUMMARY>
<MODE>product</MODE>
<VENDORLOGON>www.shoponline.co.uk</VENDORLOGON>
<VENDORREF>498</VENDORREF>
<TOTALSERVICECOUNT>1</TOTALSERVICECOUNT>
<TOTALPRODUCTCOUNT>1</TOTALPRODUCTCOUNT>
<COUNT>1</COUNT>
<SUPPLIERLOGO>
http://www.feefo.com/feefo/getnonpublicfile.jsp?vendorimage=777327&vendorimageext=file.png
</SUPPLIERLOGO>
<TITLE>Kawai ES100 Piano</TITLE>
<BEST>100</BEST>
<WORST>0</WORST>
<AVERAGE>100</AVERAGE>
<START>1</START>
<LIMIT>20</LIMIT>
<SERVICEEXCELLENT>1</SERVICEEXCELLENT>
<SERVICEGOOD>0</SERVICEGOOD>
<SERVICEPOOR>0</SERVICEPOOR>
<SERVICEBAD>0</SERVICEBAD>
<PRODUCTEXCELLENT>1</PRODUCTEXCELLENT>
<PRODUCTGOOD>0</PRODUCTGOOD>
<PRODUCTPOOR>0</PRODUCTPOOR>
<PRODUCTBAD>0</PRODUCTBAD>
<TOTALRESPONSES>18</TOTALRESPONSES>
<FEEDGENERATION>Wed Mar 12 16:05:57 GMT 2014</FEEDGENERATION>
<PRODUCTLINK>
http://shop.co.uk/product.php?id=498-Kawai-ES100-Digital-Piano-in-Black
</PRODUCTLINK>
</SUMMARY>
<FEEDBACK>
<FEEDBACKID>117</FEEDBACKID>
<COUNT>1</COUNT>
<DATE>05-Mar-2014</DATE>
<HREVIEWDATE>2014-03-05T20:07:39</HREVIEWDATE>
<DESCRIPTION>Kawai ES100 Piano</DESCRIPTION>
<PRODUCTCODE>498</PRODUCTCODE>
<LINK>
http://shop.co.uk/product.php?id=498-Kawai-ES100-Digital-Piano-in-Black
</LINK>
<FACEBOOKSHARELINK>
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.feefo.com%2FGB%2Fen%2Freviews%2Fbla%2F%3Fid%3D777327%26servicefeedbackid%3D117
</FACEBOOKSHARELINK>
<HREVIEWRATING>5</HREVIEWRATING>
<PRODUCTRATING>++</PRODUCTRATING>
<CUSTOMERCOMMENT>Great digital piano</CUSTOMERCOMMENT>
<SHORTCUSTOMERCOMMENT>Great digital piano</SHORTCUSTOMERCOMMENT>
<READMOREURL>
http://www.feefo.com/GB/en/reviews/Keysound/?id=777327&productfeedbackid=117
</READMOREURL>
</FEEDBACK>
</FEEDBACKLIST>
```

I have been trying to get the SUMMARRY COUNT into a string and then use it to see if it is 0 and if not do something if it is do something else:

please have a look at my code:

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_filename);
 $count= array((string) $xml->FEEDBACKLIST->SUMMARY->COUNT);
    if ($count == "0"){

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
    $doc->load($curdir."/feedback.xsl");
    $xsl->importStyleSheet($doc);
    $doc->load($xml_filename2);
    echo $xsl->transformToXML($doc);
    }
    else{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
    $doc->load($curdir."/feedback.xsl");
    $xsl->importStyleSheet($doc);
    $doc->load($xml_filename);
    echo $xsl->transformToXML($doc);    
    }
```

Can anybody suggest how to do this s this doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP XML. How to check if value of a tag is 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347436/php-xml-how-to-check-if-value-of-a-tag-is-0)

Comment: Can you tell us what error or result it shows?

Comment: The result shows the else statement only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define `$count` as `array`, you have to check against this array in your `if`-statement:

```
if ($count[0] == "0") { // see the index: [0]
```

As an alternative, don't define `$count`as `array`and leave the `if`-statement as it is:

```
$count = (string)$xml->SUMMARY->COUNT;
```

Note: your XML's root `<FEEDBACKLIST>` is represented in `$xml`, so do not repeat it.

Here's a working demo: https://eval.in/119164